# Intersection points of a circle and a parabola

Tags: circles, conic-sections

On solving to find the intersection points of a circle ($x^2+y^2=2$) and a parabola ($x^2=y$), we get a quadratic equation $$y^2+y-2=0$$ which gives two values  $y=1$ and $y=-2$.

With $y=1$ we get two points of intersection $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$.
But $y=-2$ doesn't lie neither on the circle nor on the parabola.
So why does the negative solution exist?

Thank you!

Comment: Substituting $y^2=4x$ in $x^2 + y^2 = 2$ should give you $x^2 + 4 x = 2$, not $y^2 + y - 2$.

Comment: Correct parabola as $x^2=y$

Answer (score 1):

$y=-2$ doesn't lie on the parabola. That much is true. But , we are looking at this only in the real plane. For $y=-2$ , we will get complex solutions, which we do not see on the real plane.

To find the complex solutions:

$$x^2+y^2=2$$
$$x^2+4=2$$
$$x^2=-2$$
$$x=\pm i\sqrt2 $$

Comment: My mistake. Correct parabola as $x^2=y$.

Comment: How does one interpret the y=-2 solution. Neither it is on the circle or on the parabola.

Comment: As @Lubin explained, $y=-2$ would not lie in the real plane, and we would have to look from the complex plane's perspective.

Comment: Thanks. How is that the discriminant of $y^2+y−2=0$ which is positive  but still we get one solution in complex form.

Comment: We get two solutions. See the answer. For each imaginary $x$ we will get two complex points with the same value of $y$

Comment: My question is , if the discriminant is positive, isn't the solution should always be real. I am talking of the intersection point, as other intersection point ends up in complex form.

Comment: @RajeshMarndi The discriminant is positive for $y$ . So we will get real values of $y$. But for those real values of $y$ , $x$ is complex. Hence you cannot plot it on the real plane

Answer (score 1):

According to a wonderful theorem of Bézout, two conic sections will ordinarily intersect in four points, counting multiplicity. But you have to allow for points with complex coordinates as well, and these will not be seen  in the real picture that we can draw.

Your two values of $x$ are $-2\pm\sqrt6$. If my hand computation is correct, the points with negative $x$-coordinate are $\bigl(-2-\sqrt6,\pm\sqrt{-9-4\sqrt6}\,\bigr)$, definitely complex.

I suppose you may ask, in the case of two circles, where the remaining two intersections are; and worse, where the four intersections of concentric circles are. There you have to go back and get the full statement of Bézout: that we must look not only in the finite plane, but in the projective plane too. But that is going beyond what I want to write about this late in the evening.

Comment: +1 Wow! I never knew this kind of thing existed. Could you please share a few links that would help me grasp this concept? ( Whenever you're free of course)

Comment: Correct parabola as $x^2=y$.

Comment: Well, @sai-kartik , there is a fairly good explanation in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout%27s_theorem .